# How do we mount a file as file instead of directory inside docke container?

Tags: java, docker

I want to execute a file in new docker container lets say i want to execute Hello.java which prints Hello World. I want to execute this file inside new docker container.

`docker run -it -v /Hello.class:/Hello.class alpine:latest ls -l`

I would fire above command using Runtime class of java.

It shows that Hello.class is a directory.
I want it as a file so that i can execute it inside new docker container.
How to do this??

Comment: The first part of `-v` needs to be an absolute path to the file on the host; do you mean `-v "$PWD/Hello.class:/Hello.class"?  Typically you would build your application into an image and `COPY` the class file (or jar file) in a Dockerfile, rather than inject it via a bind mount.

Comment: I want to inject it via mount. how to do that??

Comment: Application is dockerized. At runtime I will create a file Hello.java. I want to execute this file from my current docker container into the new docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I would suggest to make a small dockerfile for simplicity.

**Step1: Create Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:7
COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN javac HelloClass.java
CMD ["java", "HelloClass"]
```

**Step 2: Building the Docker Container**
After you have created both the JavaMain Class and the Dockerfile, you can now use the Docker build command to build your Docker Image.

```
docker build -t hello-demo .
```

**Step 3: Running the Docker Container**
Now, you can use the Docker run command to run your Docker Container.

```
docker run -it hello-demo
```

Comment: Application is dockerized. At runtime I will create a file Hello.java. I want to execute this file from my current docker container into the new docker container.